# Detaching/reattaching fragments leaves black screen on the container

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Imagine we are starting the app, we add the `FragmentA` on the backstack and according to this snippet (see below), the fragment is added to the layout, so no previous fragment is on the backstack or in the container.

When I go to Quick settings -> turn on Airplane mode (I know it might not have something to do with it, but thats the only repro), I get blank screen when I when I try to move to FragmentB.

Basically, FragmentA is still on the backstack, when FragmentB is added to the I detach FragmentA from the UI (frag: `remove` is `false`) , but it is still on the backstack.

```
public static void showFragment(FragmentActivity activity, Fragment f, boolean remove, boolean addToBackStack){
        Fragment lastFragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             if (lastFragment != null) {
                 if(!remove){
                     ft.detach(lastFragment);
                     Log.i("FragmentUtil", "Detaching fragment "+lastFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
                 }else{
                     Log.i("FragmentUtil", "Removing fragment "+lastFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
                     ft.remove(lastFragment);
                 }
             }
             if (f != null && !f.isAdded() && !f.isDetached()) {                
                     ft.add(R.id.content_frame, f, f.getClass().getName());
                     Log.i("FragmentUtil", "Adding fragment "+f.getClass().getSimpleName());
                     if(addToBackStack)
                         ft.addToBackStack(f.getClass().getName());
              } else {
                  Log.i("FragmentUtil", "Atttaching fragment "+f.getClass().getSimpleName());

                     ft.attach(f);
              } 
             ft.commit();
    }
```

Both fragments are shown with `remove = false` and `addToBackStack = true;`

`TL;DR`: Screen gets black when I have FragmentA shown and turn on Airplane mode and try to add FragmentB.

Comment: got any solution yet ?